# Best startup JSF 2.2 archetype

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsf, maven-3, eclipse-kepler

What is the best maven archetype to start a JSF 2.2 project in Eclipse EE with?

I am currently learning JSF and am looking for a clean maven archetype to start my JSF project with. I tried a few archetypes with jsf in the title, but they don't seem to create a "clean" (no problems found) in eclipse. I am looking for an answer from experience.

Comment: See this [post](http://qussay.com/2013/09/14/create-jsf-2-2-maven-project-with-primefaces-3-5-using-eclipse/)

Comment: Downvotes and no comments. Hate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no best one as every archetype comes with stuff one does not want. Since every one is different some modifications will always be required.

I would give the appfuse archetypes a try: http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart

```
mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=org.appfuse.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=appfuse-light-jsf-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=2.2.1 -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=myproject -DarchetypeRepository=http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/appfuse
```

I think they use MyFaces 2.1.9 but that should be easy to change :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one: https://github.com/ignl/happyfacescrud
It contains quite a few features out of box.

Comment: Can you please provide steps how to use it or configure it in eclipse. I am new to jsf.